# Python3: Returning random.randint with string in one line

Tags: string, random, python-3.6

```
import random
for x in range(5):
a = (random.randint(1,71))
b = "your numbers are"
c = str(a)
    print(b + c)
```

How do I get the output "your numbers are x1, x2, x3, x4, x5"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use string concatenation (below, expressions like "b +=" instead of "b =") to solve the problem like so:

```
import random

b = ""
for x in range(5):
   a = (random.randint(1,71))
   b += str(a)
   # this part is only important if you care about having commas between numbers
   if x < 4:
      b += ", "
print("your numbers are " + b)
```